# Is there an extensibility mechanism in protobuf-net to control raw de/serialization?

Tags: protobuf-net

We are using protobuf-net to serialize and de-serialize deep object graphs. Some members of these 
graphs are really repeated over and over across many graphs, as is the case for many-to-one relations to a few objects. For example, a *Sale* object would be a graph, and its *Store* member 
(possibly a sub-graph on its own) would be only one out of 10 possible stores, and thus it would be
repeated over and over across many messages (*Sale* graphs).

We could reap obvious performance benefits if we could somehow cache the serializations of these objects. Ideally, we would like to tell the *RuntimeModel* that certain types - in this case, *Store* - should be handled through an extensibilty point, much like surrogates, which would however we capable of providing the raw serialization bytes.

One of our constrains is that the generated messages should still be protobuf-net compatible, in 
order to be parsable directly by clients in other platforms (say, Python) without these "hooks" 
(screw performance optimizations for Python clients!).

We looked at surrogates, but it looks that whatever the surrogate produces (in our case that would 
be somehow a *byte*[] array) would (as you'd expect) still be serialized as its type (i.e. as a 
*byte*[] array) and thus not compatible with the *Store* object expected by Python clients.

We also looked at Extensions, and even if we somehow hacked the cached serialized *Store* in an 
extra field, we'd back to square one with Python clients.

Is there any other extensibility mechanism we might use for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ooh, interesting. Indeed, the python requirement derails what I was *going* to say (reference tracking). What you *could* do is to serialize those *first* to a `byte[]` each (via `MemoryStream`) and then just include that data as a `byte[]` member (there is no difference between a `byte[]` and the original object - external clients won't notice any differenc), but the thought occurs that in most cases this is not going to be significant faster than just keeping the object model "as is" and serialising some of the nodes multiple times (the serialization is not very slow).

Frankly, though, I would be looking at storing it a different way - so instead of storing stores as a child node, I'd have them uniquely once as top-level nodes, and just store some unique identifier as a lookup (not the child-object itself). That changs the layout, though.

No, nothing is built in to support this, and I'm not sure it is a key-scenario for supporting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marc. You say: "there is no difference between a byte[] and the original object - external clients won't notice any difference"; do you really mean that a surrogate with just a byte[] member would be "externally equivalent" to the original Store object?

Comment: @GabrieleGiuseppini as long as the structure is the same, yes. There is no structural difference between a top-level message and a nested message, other than the length-prefix: and guess what: a `byte[]` has a length-prefix. So: `Foo { Bar }` is **100% identical** to a `Foo { byte[] }` where the `byte[]` is `Bar`, serialized independently. Basically, both `byte[]` and nested messages use the string (i.e. length-prefix) wire-type: they are indistinguishable.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome. I'll do some experiments and get back to you re: the performance savings of this approach. Thanks so much!