# Protobuf-net extensions? Can I Serialize special objects in a different way?

Tags: protobuf-net

I'm new in stack overflow, I apologize if this question has been already proposed; I looked everywhere and I could not found anything. The most related subject was this

[Is there an extensibility mechanism in protobuf-net to control raw de/serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909520/is-there-an-extensibility-mechanism-in-protobuf-net-to-control-raw-de-serializat)

The thing is, I am using protobuf-net serialization method and I would like to treat some objects (special objects for several reasons) in a different way in the serialization/deserialization process.

For example say I have something like a class called Connection, that connects to a database.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Connection
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public SqlConnection myConnection {get; set}

    public Connection(String connectionString)
    {
       this.myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }           
}
```

And I would like to serialize this class using protobuf-net, when I try to do it normally:

```
public void Serialize(Object instance, string path)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, instance);
    }
}

public void someMethod()
{
    Connection p = new Connection("user id=username;" +
    "password=password;server=serverurl;" +
    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
    "database=database; " +
    "connection timeout=30");

    Serialize(p);       
}
```

I get an exception (this is not quite the problem)... Say I would like to treat this object (SqlConnection) different. Say I would like to serialize its connectionString rather than the object itself , so when I deserialize it I can connect again to the corresponding database...

I know I could do something like having another class, (the one that it is actually going to be serialized) that holds the respective information about the special object (in this case the connectionString). But that is not what I am looking for.

This is just an example, I could have more complicated objects which I would like to treat in a different way.

My question therefore is: is there a way that I could achieve this? I read about extension but I don't quite understand them.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the way to do this is via a "surrogate". Basically, you can create a type like:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SqlConnectionDto
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Server { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Database { get; set; }
    // ...

    public static explicit operator SqlConnection(SqlConnectionDto dto)
    {
        if (dto == null) return null;
        var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        { 
            DataSource = dto.Server,
            InitialCatalog = dto.Database,
            //...
        };
        return new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
    }
    public static explicit operator SqlConnectionDto(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        if (conn == null) return null;
        return new SqlConnectionDto
        {
            Server = conn.DataSource,
            Database = conn.Database,
            //...
        };
    }
}
```

and tell the engine to use it:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(SqlConnection), false)
    .SetSurrogate(typeof(SqlConnectionDto));
```

However, it does *not* currently offer total control over the serializer. Extension values are indeed an option, but without a concrete example of what you are trying to serialize it is hard to comment on whether this would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I ran the example and everything works perfectly. I think this will be good enough for the project I'm working on.